# Formatting numeric values from a text database field

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I  have a column A in MS Access formatted as text since it needs to hold alphanumeric values.

While it is holding numeric values however, I need to display only two decimal places. If the datatype is set as number, then I can achieve this by setting the format as Fixed and decimal places to 2. But the format has to work for the data type Text as well.

Note: Using VBA I'm uploading the data from Excel to MS Access.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this expression:

```
=Format(IIf(IsNumeric([YourField]), Val([YourField]), [YourField]), "0.00")
```

Comment: The formula you mentioned to be done in Excel right? But even though I'm having two decimal places in excel after uploading to Msaccess im getting more than two decimal places(data type in msaccess is text)

Comment: No, it was intended for display of the values in Access.

Comment: Could you pls give  me the steps to add that in Msaccess

Comment: Use the expression as ControlSource for a textbox.